# Remove blank lines inside <pre> Vue js

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I want to remove all the blank lines in a paragraph inside `<pre>` in a `.vue` file:

```
<div v-bind:rules="{regex: /^(?=\n)$|^\s*|\s*$|\n\n+/gm}">
      <pre>
        asdvasdvas


        asdvasdvasdv

        vasdvasdv
        asfvawfvaerfv
      </pre>
</div>
```

So that it becomes:

```
      <pre>
        asdvasdvas
        asdvasdvasdv
        vasdvasdv
        asfvawfvaerfv
      </pre>
```

But right now it is not working. Does anyone know what's wrong with my regex? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that binding `rules` attribute on a `div` should do anything with the static content of `<pre>` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your regex to `/^\s*\n/gm`

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/BaRggOZ?editors=1111) to play around with